# C# extensions for asp.net, what is the standard practice for placing the extensions file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, extension-methods

1) for asp.net (web forms), where do the extensions methods in c# go? in the web folder?

2) If the method is meant to be used in both a library and the web code behind pages, what is the correct way to allow the extensions to be used in both projects (the asp.net solution references the library project)?

3) For extensions pertaining to different types (ie. extensions for datatable, and extensions for strings), is it the standard practice to put all of them in one Extensions.cs file?

Comment: There's more than one kind of asp.net project, and different projects have different compilation models (e.g. Web Pages is different from MVC, Web Forms has/had two different models depending on whether you selected Site or Project) - what *type* of ASP.Net project(s) are we talking about?

Comment: Web forms :), I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) I'd normally place the extensions in the library project. You can use extensions from other libraries provided that the namespace of the extension class is in a `using` declaration for the code you're currently writing (indeed, that's how LINQ works)

3) I'd normally place extensions for different types into different files. In much the same way that you *can* have multiple top-level types in the same file, but the general convention is to place them in separate files. It just feels cleaner, and gives you less code to look through. It doesn't affect the experience of the code that consumes the extensions though.

Comment: nice! I didn't know extensions in other libraries can be used this way